# updating array inside another array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have mongoose model like below,

```
var product = new mongoose.Schema({
    productName: String,
    manufacturer: String,
    shotDescription: String,
    longDescription: String,
    colorNsize: [{
        color: String,
        size: [{
            sizeId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'productSizes'
            },
            MRP: Number,
            storePrice: Number,
            stock: Number
        }]
    }]
});
```

I am trying update the document's colorNsize field. My goal is to push new items into the size array of the colorNsize array.

As size is the array inside another array, i am having tough time to update.

I tried the following

```
product.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: req.body.productId
    }, {
        $push: {
            colorNsize: {
                color: req.body.color,
                $push: {
                    size: req.body
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        new: true
    },
    function (err, data) {
        return res.json(data);
    });
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.productId },
                         { 
                           $set: {colorNsize.color: req.body.color},
                           $push: {colorNsize.size: req.body}
                         }, 
                         { upsert: true, new: true},
                         function (err, data) {
                           if(err){ return res.json(err);}
                           else{return res.json(data);}
                         });
```

Comment: errmsg: "exception: cannot use the part (colorNsize of colorNsize.size) to traverse the element ({colorNsize: []})"...As colorNsize is an array we can't do the above.